# How to accurately calculate TRC20 transfer fees

Tags: tron, tronweb

To calculate the energy used by a contract invocation with TronWeb I'm using this snippet of code

```js
const { required_energy } = await tron.current.transactionBuilder.estimateEnergy(
      contractAddress,
      "transfer(address,uint256)",
      {},
      [
        { type: "address", value: address },
        { type: "uint256", value: tokenAmount }
      ]
    )
```

or you can also use the equvalent calling `triggerConstantContract` (the results are similar)

```js
const { energy_used } = await tron.current.transactionBuilder.triggerConstantContract(
      contract,
      "transfer(address,uint256)",
      {},
      [
        { type: "address", value: address },
        { type: "uint256", value: tokenAmount }
      ]
    )
```

In my case I'm trying to estimate the energy required to send USDT TRC20 `TR7NHqjeKQxGTCi8q8ZY4pL8otSzgjLj6t`

In the vast majority of the cases the energy obtained is roughly equivalent to 14 TRX.
So I can safely set the feeLimit to broadcast the transaction to 14 TRX + a little safety margin.

But then when the contract usage spikes the transaction requires like double the energy than usual, the strange thing is that the results obtained from `estimateEnergy` and `triggerConstantContract` do not follow the energy spike.

- transaction working as expected with 14 trx as fee https://tronscan.org/#/transaction/f62cf944a51803951817790fd4aeb44c85e0c5a0f101ba9d4fb9021f29bd4656
- transaction that consumed twice the trx amount https://tronscan.org/#/transaction/20a8df98b6695aeee73764efcb25ec4c313fdd56a56c60265d767c88833ac929
- transaction that went out of gas due to the unexpected behaviour https://tronscan.org/#/transaction/ea83db2e220c22530358495dfc26f9adf671de731408cfbfd51d4d6205280556

So how can I get the correct fee preview?